# How to carry a ViewBag element through a Button link

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, viewbag

I'm working on a .NET Entity Framework application which uses C# in which i'm trying to structure it so when someone registers on the application they get taken to a Add form where they create a profile.

Specifically what I'm trying to do is have the form takes the brand new UserID which generates when they register and fills in one of the fields on the form which takes that UserId and matches the new profile with the user.

I'm trying to use the concept of ViewBags to do this but I'm running into an issue.

In most cases the application views handles ViewBags with ActionLinks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("View University Course", "GetNAA_University_Courses", new { ApplicantId = ViewBag.ApplicantId, UniversityId = item.UniversityId, Controller ="NAAAdmin" })
```

However my Register function view doesn't use ActionLinks, it uses a button function like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to pass the UserId viewbag in this register method within the Account controller and as you can see it redirects the users to the AddNAA_Profile function with the Admin Controller.

```
 // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string UserId)
    {
        ViewBag.UserId = UserId;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");
                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("AddNAA_Profile", "NAAAdmin");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

Does anyone know how i can ideally pass the ViewBag variable within the Register view to the AddNAA_Profile form?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if i am not mistaking, ViewBag will get cleared if you do a `RedirectToAction()`, as it only persists in the current HTTP request. If you want it to persist through the `RedirectToAction()`, you should use `TempData["UserId"]=UserId.`

To access it in your form, you can use `@TempData["UserId"]`